# Property of $p$-variations in probability

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a continuous process. Suppose that for some $p, t > 0$, the $p$-th variation over $[0, t]$ exists and is finite: along any sequence of partitions $\pi_n = \{0 = t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_{m_n} = t\}$ of $[0, t]$ with mesh size $\|\pi_n\| \to 0$,
$$\sum_{t_k \in \pi_n} |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^p \to L_t, \quad n \to \infty,$$
where $L_t$ is almost surely finite and the convergence holds in probability. Prove that for $p' > p$, the $p'$-th variation of $X$ over $[0, t]$ equals $0$) almost surely. Moreover, prove that for $p' < p$, the $p'$-th variation equals $+\infty$ on the set $\{L_t > 0\}$.

---

I have an attempted solution for the first part, and it is as follows. Given the $p$-th variation over $[0, t]$ converges to $L_t$ for some $p, t > 0$, we consider a partition $\pi_n = \{0 = t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_{m_n} = t\}$ of $[0, t]$ with mesh size $\|\pi_n\| \to 0$. For $p' > p$, we examine the $p'$-th variation:

$$V^{p'}_n = \sum_{t_k \in \pi_n} |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^{p'}.$$

Given $p' > p$ and $|X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}| \geq 0$, properties of exponents give us:

$$|X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^{p'} < |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^{p} \text{ for } |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}| < 1.$$

As the process is continuous and $\|\pi_n\| \to 0$, for a sufficiently large $n$, $|X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|$ becomes smaller for all intervals in the partition. Thus, as $n \to \infty$, terms in the $p'$-th variation are dominated by those in the $p$-th variation, which converges to $L_t$. Since the terms in the $p'$-th variation are smaller, it follows that $V^{p'}_n \to 0$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$.

However, I'm unable to start on the second, and I would appreciate either a proof check of the first part or a proof for the second.

Comment: I don't think you can immediately infer $V_n^{p'} \to 0$ here...

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: I think you must consider how the sum's convergence is affected by the distribution of the increments $|X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|$ over the interval $[0, t]$. At least if you want to work it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We prove the first and second parts separately.

First write
$$s_t(X; \|\pi_n\|) := \sup\{|X_r - X_s| : 0 \leq r, s \leq t \text{ with } |r-s| \leq \delta\}.$$
Then since $X$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, t]$ and $\|\pi_n\| \to 0$, we must have $s_t(X; \|\pi_n\|) \to 0$ almost surely. In particular if $p' < p$,
$$\sum_{t_k \in \pi_n} |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^{p'} \leq \sum_{t_k \in \pi_n} |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^{p} \cdot s_t^{p'-p}(X; \|\pi_n\|).$$
As a result, $\sum_{t_k \in \pi_n} |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^{p'}\to 0$ in probability since $L_t$ is almost surely finite. This gives us that the $p'$-th variation of $X$ over $[0, t]$ almost surely equals $0$.

For the second part, take $p' < p$ and $\Pr[L_t > 0] > 0$. For the sake of contradiction, suppose that the $p'$-th variation is not almost surely infinite on the set $\{L_t > 0\}$, that is, there exists a sequence of partitions $\pi_n$ with mesh size $\|\pi_n\| \to 0$ such that
$$\Pr\left[\sum_{t_k \in \pi_n} |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^{p'} \not\to \infty,\, L_t > 0\right] > 0.$$
Then there must exist $0 < K < \infty$, sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$, and a subsequence $\pi_{n_i}$ of $\pi_n$ such that
$$A_n := \left\{\sum_{t_k \in \pi_n} |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^{p'} \leq K,\, L_t > 0\right\}$$
has probability $\Pr[A_n] \geq \varepsilon$. It is easy then to see that
$$\sum_{t_k \in \pi_n} |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^{p} \leq \sum_{t_k \in \pi_n} |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^{p'} \cdot s_t^{p'-p}(X; \|\pi_n\|) \leq K \cdot s_t^{p'-p}(X; \|\pi_n\|).$$
Now if $\Pr[A_n] \geq \varepsilon$, then $\Pr[A_n \text{ infinitely often}] \geq \varepsilon$. Then confined to the set $\{A_n \text{ infinitely often}\}$, it follows that
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty}\sum_{t_k \in \pi_n} |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^{p} = 0,$$
since $s_t(X; \|\pi_n\|)$ converges almost surely to $0$. However, $\{A_n \text{ infinitely often}\}$ is a subevent of $\{L_t > 0\}$, so then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{t_k \in \pi_n} |X_{t_k} - X_{t_{k-1}}|^{p} = L_t > 0,$$
which is a contradiction. The conclusion follows.

Comment: Oh, that's neat. Thanks!